# Custom simple pagination with jQuery and PHP - Finding myself stumped

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

So I'm working on my very first ever attempt at pagination (using simple Previous and Next buttons) on a for-fun project that I've undertaken. Below is all of the relevant code for my pagination system - I have left out the before and after, but I assure you that the table structure is valid.

Here is the jQuery I'm using with the elements I'm using to call the script:

```
<ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous"><a href="#" id="pagination-prev">< Previous</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a href="#" id="pagination-next">Next ></a></li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var page = 1;

        $(".pagination-page").hide();
        $(".pagination-page tbody[id=page" + page + "]").show();

        $('#pagination-prev').click(function() {
            page = page - 1;
            $(".pagination-page").hide();
            $(".pagination-page tbody[id=page" + page + "]").show();
        });

        $('#pagination-next').click(function() {
            page = page + 1;
            $(".pagination-page").hide();
            $(".pagination-page tbody[id=page" + page + "]").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I viewed the page without the jQuery active, I saw 8 `<tbody>` elements filled with dummy data that had been properly classed and id'd by the PHP script. My issue is that when I view the page with the script active, it doesn't seem to be working out for me. It hides all `.pagination-page` elements as I want, but my output has nothing toggled to show. Below is the PHP that is generating the content that I am flipping through.

```
<?php
try {
    $listed = $dbc->query("SELECT data1,data2,data3,data4 FROM `table` ORDER BY data3 DESC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

    $annPP = 15;
    $totalRows = count($listed);
    $lastPCount = $totalRows % $annPP;
    $totalPages = ceil($totalRows/$annPP);

    $place = 0;
    for ($i=1;$i<=$totalPages;$i++) {
        echo "<tbody class='pagination-page' id='page{$i}'>";

        if ($i == $totalPages) {
            // Only do the remaining rows
            $pageMax = $place + $lastPCount;
        } else {
            // Do 15 rows
            $pageMax = $i * 15;
        }
        for ($j=$place;$j<$pageMax;$j=$place) {
            $row = $listed[$j];
            echo "<tr>
                <td style='width: 25%'>";
            if ($isAdmin) {
                echo '<label class="control-label"><input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="' . $row['0'] . '"> ';
            }
            echo "<a href='view.php?id={$row[0]}'>{$row[1]}</a>";
            if ($isAdmin) {
                echo '</label>';
            }
            echo "</td>
                <td style='width: 60%'>{$row[2]}</td>
                <td class='text-center' style='width: 15%'>";
            $created = new DateTime($row[3]);
            echo $created->format('Y/m/d') . "</td>
            </tr>";
            $place++;
        }

        echo "</tbody>";
    }
}
?>
```

What did I miss? What's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `.pagination-page` to make my jQuery read as follows:

```
$("tbody[id='page" + page + "']").show;
```

Fixed the problem. Not quite sure I understand why this is, though.

Comment: .pagination-page tbody[id=page" + page + "] would suggest that tbody[id=page" + page + "] is the child of .pagination-page. But according to the code .pagination-page and tbody[id=page" + page + "] are same elements. That is the reason it worked when you removed .pagination-page. Hope this explanation helped. Cheers

Comment: Ah, okay. That explains it perfectly. Thank you!